# What does ほれ mean?

Tags: words, definitions

The following sentences in the children's book 花咲じいさん refer to a dog barking:

> 「ここほれワンワン、ここほれワンワン」
>   「おや？　ここをほれと言っているのか。

jisho.org's pretty good, but it doesn't seem to have a clear definition for ほれ.　　Google Translate doesn't shed too much insight on where to look, other than maybe something to do with fondness or belovedness (which apparently describe the dog in this story, but I'm not certain this is even the right place to look).  What ultimately does ほれ mean, especially in cases like the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[掘る]{ほる} is the verb used here.  It means to dig.  [掘れ]{ほれ} is in the [命令形]{めいれいけい} which is the imperative form of the verb [掘る]{ほる}.

Comment: If possible, could you explain why it's "ここ**を**ほれ"? Why not で? I probably didn't get to that part of grammer yet...